# Can I charge my M1 Mac Air with a higher power charger?

Tags: mac, charging

I need to know if I can charge my MacBook Air M1 using an other more powerful charger.

My phone charger is a Realme Super Dart 10 volt 6.5 ampere (65 watt) charger. I think it is adaptable to the device. I also charge another phone which needs 30 watt and it works fine. The official charger that Apple provides is 20v 1.5a or 15v 2a or 9v 3A or 5v 3A i.e. 30 watt.

I read somewhere online that if other charger is used, its voltage should be near about same to the one that Apple provides. My mobile charger is 10 volt which is quite near 9v. I know that my Mac won't charge any faster, it's just a matter of convenience of not having to carry an extra charger with me everywhere I go.

Please help me understand USB power delivery charging requirements on my Mac.

(Update : when I charge my device using my 65 watt charger, the pd that MBA shows in system report is just 5 watt. I can't understand why

Comment: You are talking about charging over USB-C, right?

Comment: I'd suggest that the right voltage is important: the wattage power rating is just a maximum capability of the charger.

Comment: USB-PD requires negotiation of both amperage and voltage (as opposed to regular USB, which only negotiates amperage and has a fixed voltage), so any compliant device _should_ work with any compliant charger, though not necessarily at the optimal wattage for either the charger or the device. Of course, blindly assuming devices and chargers are compliant is not always a safe bet, but Apple is pretty good about this and third-party stuff has been getting better in recent years about not being blatantly non-compliant with USB standards.

Comment: @nohillside yes it's a USB B to C

Answer (score 6):

There's no harm in using that charger with your MacBook Air M1.

The Realme Super Dart 65W charger does not "just" output 10V - it negotiates the voltage with the device you're charging. This means that the maximum effect that can be drawn by the device might be less than 65W.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, yes you can. They negotiate and work well. For example I'm using a Lenovo USB-C dock with a 90W capacity and it charges my M1 air with 60W.

I also have the same Realme Superdart charger and it's also showing me 5W charge. It also shows 5.4W outlet power, so it's really only at 5 watts. This means this particular charger can't negotiate a higher charging level.

Comment: But why it charging at 60W, apple gives 30W charger right?

Comment: If you look at the text on the back of the MBA M1 you find two different wattages, one is 60W. Apple gives you the 30W charger because it is cheaper and they are greedy.

Comment: @AntonioSesto Have you considered that someone buying an Air wants to be light and carries it to work and back and a 60 W charger would weight probably more than the air itself! That's why design is so important and Apple is good at it. It's not always about how much you can squeeze out of something!

Comment: No, it is not that heavy (I have a 65W, dual port charger that is as big and heavy as the original 30W) and 30W are not enough when using the MBA intensively, especially with external HD attached. Furthermore, the second wattage supported by MBA is not standard.